# Why doesn't console.log print to the CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm following a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlB_eWDSMt4) on NodeJs, and for some reason my `console.log` commands unexpectedly stopped working. Here is the sample code from the tutorial as I've typed it:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer();

server.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New connection')
});

server.listen(3000);

console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

After saving I try using `node` and `nodejs`

```
node app.js
```

```
nodejs app.js
```

but they print nothing.

Comment: Try a hello-world program to be sure your Node is working correctly.

Comment: Try with system restart.. it can save your time

Comment: "*unexpectedly stopped working*"  means that you had them working before?

Comment: Hey @Galen does it output `console.log('Listening on port 3000...');` this log at least? When you start the program?

Comment: @tadman, a separate hello world script works correctly.

Comment: @GouravGarg I tried it, but didn't change ```app.js``` from not printing anything.

Comment: @Bergi *stopped* implied it was doing it before; yes.

Comment: That code works for me as expected. I'd try commenting out everything but the last `console.log`, then uncommenting things to see where it breaks, if in fact it does or if there's something else wonky.

Comment: @Y4glory When I comment out the lines other than ```console.log('Listening on port 3000...');``` it still doesn't print the literal string.

Comment: @tadman Just tried commenting out the rest; didn't print the literal string.

Comment: Can you add code to your working hello-world app and reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Galen Then what changed since? Go back to the working state. A system restart might  indeed help. This is not a problem we can diagnose from afar.

Comment: Gah! I think this was a Visual Studio problem. Despite having saved before rebooting as advised above, it *didn't* save most of the lines in my post including the ```console.log``` statements. I specifically clicked on the source code, pressed ```[ctrl] + [s]``` and rebooted. I think I'll go back to trying to learn ```vim```.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to (1) vote to close, if so under what criterion, (2) delete the question, (3) answer it, or (4) let it sit as is?